# Public vs private key for JWT verification?

Tags: jwt

Im using JWTs with Auth0. Im verifying the token with the public key (pemCert).

However I've seen examples where the token is decoded in other ways eg with a private key. Is using the public key equally secure as other methods?

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function authoriseToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers.authorization;
  const pemCert = process.env.JWT_PEM;

  // If there is no token the user is not logged in
  if (!token || token.length === 0) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  const tokenCrop = token.replace('Bearer ', '');

  jwt.verify(
    tokenCrop,
    pemCert,
    { algorithm: 'RS256' },
    (err, decodedToken) => {
    if (err) {
      // If the token isn't verified eg expired then forward as if no token
      next();
    } else if (decodedToken) {
      // If the token is verified then add fields to the res
      req.authId = decodedToken.sub
      next();
    }
  },
);
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the usual Signed Jwt (Header. payload. signature) or encrypted tokens (JWE)?

Comment: The usual signed JWTs. The tokens are for authentication but don't contain any sensitive information (apart from the users email address)

Comment: Please be careful with the terms encoded/decoded vs. encrypted/decrypted. For decoding you don't need a key. Usually the signature is created using the private key and validated using the public key. Maybe these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999844/jwt-public-key-vs-private-key-signature-validation-what-is-the-difference) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588319/understanding-rsa-signing-for-jwt) are helpful.